# Criteria for $B$ to be a basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

In my general topology textbook they have the following proposition:

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $B$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $B$ is a basis for a topology on $X$ if an only if $B$ has the following properties:
>
> 1. $X= \bigcup _{A \in B} A$
> 2. For any $A_1, A_2 \in B$, the set $A_1 \cap A_2$ is a union of members of $B$.

Property number 1 is easy to understand: Is to make sure that $X \in \tau$ right? But what about property number 2? What's the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $B$ is a basis for a topology $\mathcal T$ if $\mathcal T$ consists of exactly the unions of subfamilies of $B$. In particular, every member $A$ of $B$ is also a member of $\mathcal T$, and therefore, since a topology must be closed under finite intersections, if $A_1,A_2\in B$ then $A_1\cap A_2\in\mathcal T$. So $A_1\cap A_2$ must be the union of some members of $B$.

Note that, if we just copied "$\mathcal T$ is closed under binary intersections" and plugged in "union of members of $B$" in place of "member of $\mathcal T$", we'd get "the intersection of any two unions of members of $B$ is itself a union of members of $B$." Property 2 is a simplified version of this, where you intersect just two members of $B$ rather than two unions of members of $B$. Fortunately, the distributive laws for $\bigcup$ and $\cap$ show that the simplified version implies the original, unsimplified version.